# LiftIO, do block, and syntax

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm getting to grips with writing an API in Haskell using Scotty. My files are provided below. My questions are:

1. In the routes definition, I'm extracting from liftIO whatsTheTime in a do block. This works, but it seems verbose. Is there a nicer syntax?
2. In the whatsTheTime definition, I'm needing to do fromString. I'd have thought OverloadedString would take care of that, but that's not the case. I'd really appreciate it if somebody pointed out why it doesn't work without fromString.
3. In a stack project, if I need a directive like OverloadedStrings, do I need to include it every file that needs it, or just at the top of the main entrypoint?

Api.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Api
    ( whatsTheTime
    ) where

import Data.Time (getCurrentTime)
import Web.Scotty
import Data.String

whatsTheTime :: IO (ActionM ())
whatsTheTime = do
    time <- getCurrentTime
    return $ text $ fromString ("The time is now " ++ show time)
```

Main.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

module Main where

import Api
import Web.Scotty
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

routes = do 
    get "/" $ do 
        res <- liftIO whatsTheTime
        res

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Starting server..."
    scotty 3000 routes
```

Comment: You're really asking multiple questions here, if you're interested in a discussion of your code the haskell subreddit or the #haskell irc channel  on freenode would probably be better than SO. Anyway, answer to your second question: `OverloadedString` only affects string literals. `String` is still a concrete datatype and `show` produces a `String`. Looks like you need `Text` in your code though, which is a different datatype, so you need a function `String -> Text` (which `fromString` conveniently is). Third question, yes, every file.

Comment: If you don't want to put it in every file, you can put it in the `default-extensions` section of your cabal file.

Comment: Why does `whatsTheTime` have type `IO (ActionM ())`, and not `ActionM ()`? In `ActionM` you can perform any `IO` actions, because it has instance `MonadIO` and you can use `liftIO`. Then your code would be more simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) This:

```
do
  res <- liftIO whatsTheTime
  res
```

Desugars to this:

```
liftIO whatsTheTime >>= \ res -> res
```

If you look at the type of `\ m -> m >>= id`:

```
(Monad m) => m (m a) -> m a
```

That’s exactly the type of `join` ([Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28Monad+m%29+%3D%3E+m+%28m+a%29+-%3E+m+a)), so you can use:

```
get "/" $ join $ liftIO whatsTheTime
```

`join` is a common idiom for “execute this action which returns an action, and also execute the returned action”.

(2) `OverloadedStrings` is for overloading of string *literals*. You have an overloaded literal `"The time is now "`, but you constrain it to be of type `String` by using it as an operand of `(++)` with a `String` (the result of `show time`). You can pack the result of `show time` as a `Text` instead using `fromString` or `Data.Text.pack`:

```
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import qualified Data.Text as Text

-- ...

return $ text $ "The time is now " <> Text.pack (show time)
```

(3) `LANGUAGE` pragmas operate per file; as @mgsloan notes, you can add `OverloadedStrings` to the `default-extensions:` field of your library or executable in your `.cabal` file.